# What does 则 mean in ...而今年的9月20日则是安室奈美惠40岁的生日?

Tags: usage, word

*(Let me first write in Mandarin)*

关于这个句子：

> 据悉，9月16日是安室奈美惠的出道纪念日，而今年的9月20日**则**是安室奈美惠40岁的生日。

关于“则”的用法，我的词典有这些说明：

- rule, standard (noun)
- follow an example (verb)
- item (measure word)

这些都看来不合适。所这个句子上“则”是什么意思？此外“则”的词性是什么？

---

*(The original sentence in English, in case my Mandarin doesn't make sense)*

In the following sentence:

> 据悉，9月16日是安室奈美惠的出道纪念日，而今年的9月20日**则**是安室奈美惠40岁的生日。

In my dictionary, 则 means:

- rule, standard (noun)
- follow an example (verb)
- item (measure word)

All of them seem to be not the case here. So what does 则 mean here and what does it function as (e.g. adverb, noun, verb, etc...)?

---

Please write an answer in English since I'm not sure if I understand it yet...

Comment: see  online dictionaries, bkrs： (conjunction used to express contrast with a previous clause) but, in the present case "on the other hand" might be a possible translation
V cons.
SV 则 SV: It's SV all right, (but)
好则好，就是太贵。 It's good all right, but it's too expensive.［more to follow]

Comment: @user6065 What is bkrs?

Comment: dictionary, search web using "bkrs"

Comment: ＂汉英虚词词典＂：则（副词）A 表示后一情况与前一情况形成对比，有＂却＂的意思，多用于书面语：But, on the other hand: indicates a contrast between the preceding and the following, and is usually used in the written language:1.要读好书，。。。基础要求广，钻研～要求深。（吴晗［谈谈书］）２。我每天晚上要给她讲两个故事，一个是＂有趣＂的，一个～是不那么＂有趣＂的。（茹志鹃［静静的产院］）３。许多展览馆里的解说员，多半是手拿长棍子呆板的背诵解说词，而飞天～完全不是这样。（刘克［飞天］）４。任何红红烈烈的事业，对那长年累月实际上参与其事的人来说，～是细微的，琐屑的，从旁看来，甚至是单调的。（王汶石［黑风］）５。。。。只见教授微微皱起眉头，若有所思地凝视着窗外，女作曲家～不时举目望着丁洁琼。（张扬（第二次握手］）６。玉菡仍然坐在软垫靠椅上，用双手托着两腮，垂目沉思；有时～久久凝视着丈夫。（张扬［第二次握手］）７。自杀是逃避现实，结婚～是屈膝投降，这两选择都很不符合苏冠兰的性格。（张扬［第二握手］）B 表示前面是原因、条件，后面是结果：相当于＂就＂：
Similar to 就,indicates that the 1st part of the

Comment: sentence introduces the cause or condition, and the 2nd part presents the result:1.空气中微粒污染物与二氧化硫的减少，～会降低污染导致的死亡。（报）２。如集思广益，～会想出比较好的办法。３。合～势大，分～势孤。（歌阳山［三家巷］）４。对录取工作中违反纪律者，轻～批评教育，重～按党纪国法惩处。（报）参看连词＂则＂。                                                        

则：（连词）［书］有＂那么＂的意思，用在后一分句前，表示顺接：Then, in that case;used at the beginning of the second clause:1.要批评托尔斯泰，～他的作品是必得看几本的。（鲁迅［读几本书］）２。。。要结交这般人，～陆慕游的线索自不可少。（矛盾［动摇］）３。严冬一封锁了大地的时候，～大地满地裂着口。（肖红［呼兰河传］）

Comment: Q about "而。。。则＂ has been answered at this site (at least once) before, see answer by gcd0318 (answer #2) to 
https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/16767/meaning-of-%e5%88%99%e6%98%af-in-this-sentence/16782#16782

Answer (score 3, accepted):

则 here, as an adverb, means 'yet'. The structure of 而...则... could be interpreted as 'while'.

So, "而今年的9月20日则是安室奈美惠40岁的生日。" is "while Sep. 20th this year will be the 40th birthday of Anshinaimeihui's."

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks. So without 而 it is not a valid sentence?

Comment: 而 is necessary as a conjunction word between that two sentences.

Comment: Thanks. BTW does my Chinese make sense in the original post...?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what bits of her name belong together. She is Japanese I believe.

This 则 just emphasizes the close connection in time, anniversary - birthday, both in September, only 4 days apart. You could just leave it out. In English you might just say the 'and' with more emphasis.

据悉，
According to reports,
9月16日是安室奈美惠的出道纪念日，
16th September is the anniversary of An Shi Nai Mei Hui's first public performance,
而今年的9月20日则是安室奈美惠40岁的生日。
and this year on the 20th of September，An Shi Nai Mei Hui will also be 40 years old

Comment: She is a Japanese singer, and her name in hiragara in Japanese is あむろなみえ, Amuro Namie.

Comment: @Huang Thanks for the follow-up!